# Question about notation used for planar vector fields and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

I have learned in my calculus courses that a planar vector field is just a continuous (or smooth) map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, say $V(x,y) = (f(x,y),g(x,y))$ where $f$ and $g$ are continuous (smooth) maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

But I've seen an example, in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixteenth_problem#The_second_part_of_Hilbert%27s_16th_problem) wiki page on Hilbert's $16^{\text{th}}$ problem, where a planar vector field is written just as a system of $2$ ODEs, in this case

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=P(x,y), \frac{dy}{dt} = Q(x,y) $$

for polynomials $P,Q$ in two variables.

Could one equivalently write the above vector field as $V(x,y)=(P(x,y),Q(x,y))$? Why is it written with ODEs instead of the other way? What differences are there between these two ways of constructing vector fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. It is just two different ways to look at the same thing.

Using your notation $V=(P,Q)$, you have an ODE in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
\frac{d\vec x}{dt}=V(\vec x)
$$
where $\vec x:=(x,y)$.

One can write an (evolutionary) equation in higher dimensional space component-wise and have a *system* of equations.

There are lots of such examples. For instance, on [this](https://www.britannica.com/science/Navier-Stokes-equation) page the system of Navier-Stokes equations is written in the vector form while the [official problem description](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf) in the Clay Mathematics Institute writes it component-wise.

This is similar to how you write a linear equation. For example,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\
3&4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
7
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
x+2y=3,\quad 3x+4y=7.
$$

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @PaulCusson you are welcome!